# Do LED dimmers work with non-LED bulbs?

Tags: lighting, led, dimmer-switch

I've been switching to LED bulbs wherever I can for the past few years but one thing I haven't done yet is switch my dimmer switches over to LED compatible dimmers. One issue I've had trouble understanding is if I can use non-LED bulbs on the dimmable circuit after switching it to LED compatible dimmer.

Comment: yes, newer dimmers still work with incandescent bulbs. The only real performance difference will be the slope; they are more precise on the dim end. Since tungsten bulbs need a certain minimum, you might have slightly more "dead zone" before the bulb kicks on. You will still have full dimming range though, just a little more sensitivity due to "0%" starting at, say, "25%"; probably not even noticeable to most folks.

Answer (score 2):

#### Probably...but check the fine print

There are a number of different light technologies in use (e.g., incandescent, halogen, fluorescent, LED) and dimmers have evolved to handle each new type. But some are easier to dim than others. **In general**, if you have a light that is dimmable then if you use a new dimmer it will work with it as well as newer technology lights.

For example, [this Lutron dimmer](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Lutron-Skylark-Contour-C-L-Dimmer-Switch-for-Dimmable-LED-Halogen-and-Incandescent-Bulbs-Single-Pole-or-3-Way-White-CTCL-153PDH-WH/202517700) can work with:

- Up to 150W of LED or CFL (provided the LED or CFL bulbs themselves are rated as dimmable - not all of them are)
- Up to 600W of incandescent or halogen

You might wonder why fewer Watts of LED & CFL bulbs work than incandescent or halogen. There are technical reasons, *but it doesn't matter* because 150W of LED is comparable to 600W (or more!) of incandescent lighting - i.e., with any technology enough to light up a large room.

On the other hand, [this less expensive dimmer from the same manufacturer/product line](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Lutron-Skylark-600-Watt-Single-Pole-Slide-to-Off-Dimmer-White-S-600H-WH/100089584) can handle 600W of incandescent/halogen *but clearly states that it is not LED or CFL*.

So the new dimmers are designed to handle the old light bulbs as well. Otherwise there would be a lot of problems as people upgrade dimmers without replacing the light bulbs at the same time. But plenty of people find out the hard way that you can't necessarily put a new bulb (LED or CFL) on an old dimmer.